# Getting a wrong footprint for my binary executable

Tags: c, size, bin

I am actually getting a wrong footprint for my binary executable when I ran the command `size <my_binary>`.

From the obtained output (which is shown below), the bss value is coming out to be in terms of 1GB but it should actually be around 150KB. Someone please let me know what is the reason for this and how to fix this issue.

```
  text    data      bss         dec        hex     filename
1279974  247448  1073768352  1075295774  4017b61e     bin
```

Comment: The BSS segment contains the uninitialized global variables. Maybe it also contains the request for the stack and the heap?

Comment: Somewhere, you’ve defined a vast uninitialized array.  There’s nothing more we can say since there is no code.  Run size on the individual object files.  That’ll tell you which ones is causing trouble.  Or maybe you’re linking with a static library and the trouble is in there.